# Getting error while staring kibana v 7.12.0 on local on windows

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I download the **Kibana** version 7.12.0, tried starting it locally from windows batch file. But I am getting the following error-

`Unable to complete saved object migrations for the [.kibana] index. TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined`

I am able to run **Elastic Search** v 7.12.0.

```
{
  "name" : "DESKTOP-07QEN6L",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "laDSNVpKQhWTIWEjdq2lDw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.12.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "zip",
    "build_hash" : "78722783c38caa25a70982b5b042074cde5d3b3a",
    "build_date" : "2021-03-18T06:17:15.410153305Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.8.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

**I have Java 8 installed and configured in my Windows 64 bit system.**

Can someone help me out? Is it a compatibility issue with Java 8? Do I need JAVA 11 or higher version?
I saw an warning while starting up ELastic Search locally, about it supporting JAVA 11 or higher.

Comment: you dont need java 11. please share your kibana.yml

Comment: I deleted and download again, then i tried , it worked!